# "Unable to merge dex" error when update to Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: android

This error appears after I updated to Android Studio 3.0. I tried many ways in many similar questions, but nothing works.

Here is the error:
[image]

I realized that when I remove the library 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2' my project build successful. But I need this library in my project, anyone knows how to deal with this problem?

My complete build.gradle.

`buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vn.com.ttsoft.dhd"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.pavlospt:roundedletterview:1.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
}`

Comment: have you enabled multidex?

Comment: i also had an error on upgrading but i am not sure what it was exactly. clean and build project solved it for me.

Comment: @war_Hero yes, I had "multiDexEnabled true" in defaultConfig.

Comment: @woodii I also try clean and rebuild but it stills error.

Comment: can you post the complete build.gradle

Comment: @jacky remove the google-play-services.jar from your project and from gradle also and add dependency of that jar `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2' `in gradle and then try again.

Comment: @war_Hero I updated question and add complete build.gradle code.

Comment: try adding this inside android `dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }`

Comment: @AmjadKhan it comes with the same error.

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Comment: Invalidated cache in IDE and then deleted  .gradle directory in my project file and re runned the app. This helped me.

Comment: I tried all of your suggest methods, none of these works. I think there are some problems between gradle 3.0.0 and google play services. I just downgraded to gradle 2.3.3 so I can run my app. I'll keep looking for better solution to deal with gradle 3.0.0 later.
Thanks all :)

Comment: See my answer below. You are compiling Play Services 3 times. Here... compile `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2` , Here... `compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')` and finally here... `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`. Gradle 2.3.3 was forgiving. Gradle 3.0.0 doesn't like the multiple Dex and throws the build error. Either remove the .jar file or remove `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2`

Comment: ... The irony is that when you "remove the library 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2' my project build successful." you actually fixed the problem, because the library was still being built from the .jar file in your \libs  :)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Play Services do you load from file? I guess that's an issue, you try to load whole play services and partial `play-services-maps` together. Also that explains the fact that, when you remove maps, everything works fine.

take a look on this link for selective compiling play services APIs, this will also help to reduce method count
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: why -1 point? :/ problem is that OP trying to load .jar library instead

Comment: not me, I didn't click down arrow :)
anyway, thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting the gradle file you can use it may help you

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "vn.com.ttsoft.dhd"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            // Disable fabric build ID generation for debug builds
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.pavlospt:roundedletterview:1.2'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'me.tatarka.support:jobscheduler:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

and another project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and I think something is wrong with google play services dependencies so I got it resolved by adding all below google play services dependencies :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the 'Multiple Dex' build error after upgrading to AS 3.0 / Gradle 3.0.0.

I found that the invalidate caches and restart, clean project, and minifyEnabled "solutions" were all red herrings.

I struggled with this for a few hours then found out what was causing my problem.

I was compiling `Picasso`, `GSON` and `SQLiteAssetHelper` using the statements

```
        compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

...but I also had the sqliteassethelper, GSON and Picasso `.jar` files being compiled from my `\libs` folder.

```
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Hence the duplicates.

Yes - pretty obvious but sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees!

I hope this helps someone.

(Final Note: `compile` command is deprecated in Gradle 3.0.0, therefore you might wish to change the above commands from `compile` to `implementation`)

Comment: This answer relates to Android 3.0 stable version and NOT Beta 4. It's therefore been removed from the Beta 4 question and reinstated for this question. Of course there can be questions that are similar but that are not the same. Unless searchers then come here, they won't find possibly relevant answers. I initially posted a link to this answer but that was edited out by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

To somebody who is using `android-async-http` and had tried `enable DEX`, `invalidate cache`, `delete .gradle files` and `check duplicate import/version`:

I have some conflict in `org.apache` and `android-async-http` packages,

after I change i.e. `org.apache.http.Header`
to `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header`, my problem solved.

```
{       
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'  // avoid this
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar') // only keep this one
}
```